# Python Flask application - How to make html input tag with dropdown updated by javascript ajax function

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I am trying to make the input tag with id="livebox" be a live search box with surgestions from youtube. Does any one know how to add a dropdown surgestions box to the input tag with surgestions from `res` in the javascript?

The `console.log(res)` outputs `['sidemen', 'sannevillefamily', 'stor mand', 'spiderman', 'signe kragh', 'ssundee', 'sam and colby', 'speed', 'stille musik', 'speak no evil trailer', 'sleep music', 'stranger things season 4', 'spørg casper', 'shakira']` if "s" is typed in the input.

All the code used is as follows:

Flask code .py

```
import requests
import re
from isodate import parse_duration
from flask_youtube_search.common import myShelvedDict
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, current_app, request, redirect,jsonify,url_for  

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():   
    return render_template('index.html',data=[])

@main.route("/livesearch",methods=["POST","GET"])
def livesearch():
    searchbox = request.form.get("text")
    URL = f"https://suggestqueries-clients6.youtube.com/complete/search?client=youtube&hl=da&gl=dk&gs_rn=64&gs_ri=youtube&ds=yt&cp=5&gs_id=l&q={searchbox}&xhr=t&xssi=t"
    r = requests.get(url = URL)
    data = r.text
    data = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', data)
    data = data[1:(len(data)-5)]
    myShelvedDict["data"] = data
    data = tuple(data)
    print(data)
    return jsonify(data)
```

html code for index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Search YouTube</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='album.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<main role="main">
  <section class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Search YouTube</h1>
      <p class="lead text-muted">Get the top nine results on YouTube for your query!</p>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input list="surgestions" type="text" id = "livebox" name="query">
        <p>{{data}}</p>
      </div>
      <form action ="search" method="POST">
      <p>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-primary my-2">YouTube Search</button>
      </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
  
</main>
</body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#livebox").on("input",function(e){
          $("#datalist").empty();
          $.ajax({
              method:"post",
              url:"/livesearch",
              data:{text:$("#livebox").val()},
              success:function(res){
                  console.log(res);
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

unimportant css code:

```
.jumbotron {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .jumbotron {
    padding-top: 6rem;
    padding-bottom: 6rem;
  }
}

.jumbotron p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  max-width: 40rem;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

footer p {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.jumbotron-video {
  text-align: center;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
}
.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 12.5%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
}

.embedded-video-16-9 {
  width:  90vw;
  height: 50.625vw; /* 90*9/16 */
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}

@media (min-width: 893px) {
  .embedded-video-16-9 {
    width: 45vw;
    height: 25.3125vw; /* 45*9/16 */
    margin-left: 2vw;
    margin-right: 2vw
  }
}
```

Unimportant import commom.py

```
import shelve

myShelvedDict = shelve.open("my_shelved_dictionary.db")
```

Comment: So you want to have a autosuggestion that updates the suggested items based on the input? (e.g. if the users inputted "hello" then a function would be run and return a new list of items to be suggested)

Comment: Yes, every time the user types a request is send to the youtubes api and the api returns suggestions for what the user typed in and then I would like to have those suggestions updated to the field where the user is typing. So every keystroke updates the input dropdown list with new suggestions. This basically makes input field become the youtube search bar from youtube.

Comment: There is this thing called jquery-ui that have an autocomplete, would you like me to show how would it be applied? It basically makes the dropdown list for you, you could check their docs here: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. I implemented a similar idea in which I check if the user typed and stopped for x time (like typed and stopped for 2 seconds) then query the database/run a function then return a new list for jquery-autocomplete to serve real time

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved it now.

The fix was to use following script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#livebox").on("input",function(e){
          var _this = $(this);
          $("#datalist").empty();
          $.ajax({
              method:"post",
              url:"/livesearch",
              data:{text:$("#livebox").val()},
              success:function(res){
                $("#query").empty();
                for (var i in res) {
                    $("<option/>").html(res[i]).appendTo("#query");
                }
                _this.focus();
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

with the html:

```
<input autoComplete="off" list="query" type="text" id = "livebox" name="query">
<datalist id="query"></datalist>
```